# What arthropod with a distinctive yellow and black colored body is this?

Tags: species-identification, arthropod

I found this outside my window, today morning, on a clothes peg;

[image]

[image]

I live on the eighteenth floor, so it probably is a good flyer.

I have noticed that the antennae are almost as long as its body and the legs are yellow, not dark.

Nothing peculiar about the behavior-- it moved around on the peg, for a while, and then flew away.

**Location**- Bangalore, India.

**Length** - ~2cm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a *[Glenea multiguttata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glenea_multiguttata)*, a beetle species found in India.

Compare: [image: Glenea multiguttata] from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Black_and_Yellow_Longhorn_Beetle_005.JPG